# angularjs select with multiple freeze in IE

Tags: angularjs, performance, internet-explorer

I have an angular app where I have a select option with MULTIPLE attribute where user can select more than one value. When I use CTRL or SHFT to select the values, the application is freezing. I see about this issue many times, but nobody gave a correct way how to fix it. Does anybody have a solution.

```
<select size="12" 
        multiple data-ng-required="sItem.mustBeSelected" 
        data-ng-model="sItem.SelectedItems" 
        data-ng-init="sItem.SelectedItems;DoFilter(sItem)" 
        data-ng-selected="sItem.SelectedItems" 
        data-ng-change="DoFilter(sItem)" 
        data-ng-options="option as checktodisplayCodenLabel(option,sItem.showCodeOnLabel) | replaceNBSP disable when option.disabled==true for option in sItem.refData | filter: search track by option.vm ">   
</select>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of your code?

Comment: <select  size="12" multiple    data-ng-required="sItem.mustBeSelected"
        data-ng-model="sItem.SelectedItems" 
          data-ng-init="sItem.SelectedItems;DoFilter(sItem)" 
          data-ng-selected="sItem.SelectedItems"
                                                           data-ng-change="DoFilter(sItem)" 
                                                           data-ng-options="option as checktodisplayCodenLabel(option,sItem.showCodeOnLabel) | replaceNBSP disable when option.disabled==true for option in sItem.refData | filter: search track by option.vm ">          </select>

Comment: we need more data. Which IE version are you using ? can you provide example of data ?

Comment: Using IE11. I am not sure if I can share the data. There are 2 SELECT options, one Area and other Item. When Area selected, user can select more than one Item. Each Area element has atleast 200 items,